# Does RPM (5400 vs 7200) matter for a secondary internal laptop data drive?

Tags: hard-drive

I am wanting put a secondary internal hard drive in my laptop. My primary drive is a 7200RPM / 64GB SSD hybrid which performs really well.  I want to install another hard drive purely for data, mainly GIS (Geographic Information Systems) spatial data and file spatial geodatabases as well as for photography data such as Adobe Lightroom files (some form of a non-destructive database), image RAW files and photoshop files. 
Basically, **the files I will be accessing are large but aside from the RAW image files and large TIFF files they are likely very fragmented.**

Solid state drive for purely data is not an option right now ($) because I need 1TB but I am curious what is more suitable for a secondary "data" drive; 5400 RPM  or 7200RPM?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Would I notice the difference between a 7200 rpm and a 5400 rpm laptop hard drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/227042/would-i-notice-the-difference-between-a-7200-rpm-and-a-5400-rpm-laptop-hard-driv), [What is the difference between a 5400 RPM and a 7200 RPM HDD in terms of speed?](http://superuser.com/questions/322052/what-is-the-difference-between-a-5400-rpm-and-a-7200-rpm-hdd-in-terms-of-speed?lq=1)

Comment: You wouldn't really notice any speed difference between those speeds.  You have other bottleknecks at play besides the RPM of the drive.

Comment: `Does RPM (5400 vs 7200) matter for a secondary internal laptop data drive?` - No it does not.

Comment: @joeqwerty - I am don't know all the technicalities but I though there are differences for different applications; number of plates, density, access of packed data at different speeds, more importantly access of large chunks of data vs fragmented data.  I've read 5400RPM might be better in some situations - in my case I know i will be accessing highly fragmented data.

Comment: Sure there are, but you're talking about a drive that will be used relatively infrequently for relatively static data, right? Therefore the spindle speed is likely not a factor that you should spend a lot of time worrying about.

Comment: Data is accessed frequently; application is on the primary drive but in all cases the data is some form of a file database (Lightroom, GIS) with a lot of read/write instructions going back and forth.

Answer (score 3):

A 7200 RPM is going to read faster than the 5400 because of the spindle speed, however a lot of benching has been shown to show that the benefits are minimal. While a 7200 RPM drive will give you slightly better performance, focus more on cache size. A 64MB cache will give you considerably better performance than a 32 or 16MB cache.

The actual benefit in regard to speed between the two drives is negligible.  If I were you, I would suggest taking a look at an SSD if you need to replace a laptop hard drive.   You will get a huge performance boost from any SSD when you compare it to a spinning hard drive.

This is only my suggestion, but stay far away from Western Digital if at all possible.   I've done hundreds of RMAs over the past 10 years and 85% have been for WD hard drives.   I do not work nor have I worked for any hard drive manufacturer, nor am I a consultant or spokesperson for any computer hardware manufacturer.   This statement is based only on personal experience.  Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Good point about WD.  I had 3 of those fail on me. SSD is not an option due to cost. I need a 1TB drive. This drive will be a secondary data drive.  My question deals with fragmented data rather than large chunks of data. Just wanted an informed opinion because I read that for certain types of data 5400 might be more suitable.

Comment: If you find my response to be suitable, please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of speed you will not see significant difference. However you may see a significant advantage going with the 5400 drive because of temperature. You have not specified but I will assume you have one of those laptops that has multiple HD bays. In that case the heat produced might be the most important factor. And comparing 5400 to 7200 RPM drives there is a significant difference in heat so I would stick with 5400

Comment: Good point. Yes, this is the Alienware 17 with 2 extra bays for internal hard drive. I think is't cooled pretty well but It is a consideration for sure.